# unable to see Maven In Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I installed M2E plugin in Eclipse Mars and also Maven is installed in my system but I was unable to see an Maven option while I'm trying to import the maven project and also unable to see Maven option while trying to configure existing Java project to Maven project.

Comment: show us maven, OS versions... also hardware if possible

Comment: Apache-Maven-3.0.3 is the maven version and OS version is windows 7 64-bit, and it is in remote machine which is having 8 GB RAM. Any more hardware details required..?

Comment: update your question, don't add info@comments

Comment: check also if all soft is 64-bit version

Comment: @mssuryakumar, you mean when you open `File->Import...` and search for `Maven` you don't get to see anything ?

Comment: You need to add Maven nature to the project

Comment: yes @Shmulik Klien

Comment: @mssuryakumar What about when trying to search for maven in `Preferences` search box ? What about `mvn -version` from shell ? is it working ?

Comment: yeah While I'm searching for version it is showing the installed version. Here I need one clarification when I have all 64-bit trio then should i also have 64 bit Excel driver installed to establish the JDBC-ODBC connection @joc

Answer (score 1):

If you have all correct (64b) versions, follow [this steps](http://Alternatively%20use%20your%20preferred%20archive%20extraction%20tool.%20%20Add%20the%20bin%20directory%20of%20the%20created%20directory%20apache-maven-3.3.9%20to%20the%20PATH%20environment%20variable%20%20Confirm%20with%20mvn%20-v%20in%20a%20new%20shell.%20The%20result%20should%20look%20similar%20to%20%20Apache%20Maven%203.3.3%20(7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06;%202015-04-22T04:57:37-07:00)%20Maven%20home:%20/opt/apache-maven-3.3.3%20Java%20version:%201.8.0_45,%20vendor:%20Oracle%20Corporation%20Java%20home:%20/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre%20Default%20locale:%20en_US,%20platform%20encoding:%20UTF-8%20OS%20name:%20%22mac%20os%20x%22,%20version:%20%2210.8.5%22,%20arch:%20%22x86_64%22,%20family:%20%22mac%22%20Windows%20Tips%20Check%20environment%20variable%20value%20e.g.%20echo%20%25JAVA_HOME%25%20%20C:%5CProgram%20Files%5CJava%5Cjdk1.7.0_51%20Adding%20to%20PATH:%20Add%20the%20unpacked%20distribution%E2%80%99s%20bin%20directory%20to%20your%20user%20PATH%20environment%20variable%20by%20opening%20up%20the%20system%20properties%20(WinKey%20+%20Pause),%20selecting%20the%20%E2%80%9CAdvanced%E2%80%9D%20tab,%20and%20the%20%E2%80%9CEnvironment%20Variables%E2%80%9D%20button,%20then%20adding%20or%20selecting%20the%20PATH%20variable%20in%20the%20user%20variables%20with%20the%20value%20C:%5CProgram%20Files%5Capache-maven-3.3.9%5Cbin.%20The%20same%20dialog%20can%20be%20used%20to%20set%20JAVA_HOME%20to%20the%20location%20of%20your%20JDK,%20e.g.%20C:%5CProgram%20Files%5CJava%5Cjdk1.7.0_51%20%20Open%20a%20new%20command%20prompt%20(Winkey%20+%20R%20then%20type%20cmd)%20and%20run%20mvn%20-v%20to%20verify%20the%20installation.).

---

## Installing Maven in Windows

- Extract Maven zipped file in any folder (preferible `C:\Program Files\`)
- Add the `bin` directory of the created directory `apache-maven-3.0.3` to the `PATH` environment variable.
- Check environment variable value e.g.

  ```
  echo %JAVA_HOME%
  ```

  Must look like:

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
  ```
- **Adding Maven folder to PATH:**

  - Add the **unpacked** distribution’s `bin` directory to your user `PATH` environment variable by opening up the system properties (<kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>)
  - Select the “Advanced” tab, and the “Environment Variables” button
  - Selecting the PATH variable in the user variables with the value and addd to it `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.9\bin`. **Check your folder is same!!!**
  - If not set, the same dialog can be used to set `JAVA_HOME` to the location of your `JDK`, e.g. *`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51`*
- **Verifying**

  - Open a new command prompt (<kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
  - type `cmd`
  - run `mvn -v` to verify the installation.